# Folder's Email Address

Tags: box-api

Can you retreive a folder's specified email address via the box.net api?  I know the feature is available in the application, but not sure if it is available for access via the API.

Answer (score 0):

There is functionality for this in the v1 API: http://developers.box.net/w/page/35640290/APiFunction_toggle_folder_email